# Error Invalid grant: refresh token is invalid in getRefreshToken

Tags: node.js, model, sql-grant, oauth2-server

I want to implement the function `getRefreshToken` with the oauth2-server module in Nodejs. I already implemented the whole password grant type successfull. But now I want to implement the refresh_token grant. I'm facing a problem by implementing the `getRefreshToken` function in the models.

If I call the refresh_token route with the grant_type: refresh_token and the refresh_token I'm getting back the error message:

> "Invalid grant: refresh token is invalid".

I never check if the `refreshToken` is valid/expired or not. I just want to implement a dummy function which should return me a new accessToken.

What am I doing wrong?

```
getRefreshToken: (refreshToken, callback) => {
    const token = {
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        client: 'client1',
        user: 'UserIdXY'
    }

    callback(false, token);
}
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model/spec.html#getrefreshtoken-refreshtoken-callback) seems that `client` should be an object with property `id`, but I don't know if that's the case

Comment: Jeah as simple as it is. Changed the client to an client object an added property id. It's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://oauth2-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model/spec.html#getrefreshtoken-refreshtoken-callback) you should change `client: 'client1',` to

```
client: {id: 'client1'},
```